# Projecting new points on pca of second degree MATLAB

Tags: matlab, k-means, pca

I am trying to use PCA to visualize my implementation of k-means algorithm. I am following the tutorial on Principal Component Coefficients, Scores, and Variances in [this link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pca.html#btjpztu-1).

I am using the following command: `[coeff,score,~]=pca(X');` where X is my data.

My data is a 30 by 455 matrix, that is 30 features with 455 samples. I have successfully used the score parameter to create a 2D plot for visualization purposes. Now I wish to project the 30 dimensional center to that plain. I have tried `coeff*centers(:,1)` but I do not understand if this is the correct usage.

How do I project a new 30 dimensional point to the 2D of the first vs the second pca components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that by `centers(:, 1)` you denote a new observation. To express this observation in the principal components you should write

```
[coeff, score, ~, ~, ~, mu]=pca(X');   %return the estimated mean "mu"
tmp = centers(:, 1) - mu';   %remove mean since pca() by default centers data
coeff' * tmp;   % the new observation expressed in the principal components
```

Note that you have to subtract the mean since `pca()` by default centers the data. Also, note the transpose `'` on coeff. In fact it should be `inv(coeff)`, but since `coeff` is an [orthogonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix) we can use transpose instead.

Comment: The `centers(:, 1)` denotes a k-means center of cluster. I want to visualize in 2D where is that center.

Comment: If I have normalized and centered the data before using the pca, do I still need to subtract the mean from the new point?

Comment: You don't have to subtract `mu` if the data is already centered. You can verify that the the data is centered by checking that `mu` is zero. `mu` is just the same as `mean(X')`.